# GORM Use explicit column names in selects

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

I'm using GORM for mapping MySQL DB tables which may have extra columns that are not part of the GORM models for them.

Selecting any row form such a table crashes because GORM emits a `SELECT * FROM ...` query and tries to scan the results in the model struct which is obviously impossible because there are more returned columns than expected.

Is there a way to force GORM to explicitly name the columns in the emitted `SELECT` queries?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/scope.go#L732), it does not seem like it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible by configuration, look the following config:

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
  QueryFields: true,
})

db.Find(&user)
// result with this option {QueryFields: true}
// SELECT `users`.`name`, `users`.`age`, ... FROM `users`
```

For more info check the official docs in: https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields